# Can two servers run on the same machine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I am working on hosting a Minecraft server on one of my home machines. I would like to have two completely separate servers for certain reasons. I have successfully created one vanilla server using the standard MC server download and the instructions on the official wiki. Is it possible to run another server instance on the same machine simultaneously, perhaps out of a different port, without them interfering with each other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you should be able to do this. You'll have to port forward for each server.  I found [this post](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130207161603AA7GlBd) that explains how it works.

Basically you do the port forwarding and when you want someone to join, give them the IP followed by the port number separated by a colon. An example would be:

`111.222.333.10:25555`

Your other server would be something like:

`111.222.333.10:25556`

Just keep in mind that running multiple servers is going to put a heavier burden on the machine.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look into [Bungeecord](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bungeecord/). It's specifically designed for that purpose. It's a special type of server that "bungee"s servers together. Many servers have done this. Use this video for a [startup guide](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0ViRZPLuBiA).